# nginx serve different html file for googlebot

Tags: nginx, googlebot

I have an angular app served through nginx. For googlebot I want to serve a different static html file so that it can index properly, is the following nginx config correct? (I don't want to complicate the setup using phantomjs, I want to explore other options like sitemap.xml only if nginx can't do this job)

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ Googlebot) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /forgooglebot.html break;
    }
    root /usr/share/nginx/app;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Did you...try it?

Comment: Set your browser's user agent to Googlebot and see if it's working.

Comment: It works indeed. thanks. verified using "curl -A Googlebot" command